# Get data from SecureStore and save in a state

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to save username in `username` state. Now in console **I can't see** username when I run `componentDidMount`.

But if I put a button and I press it I can see username.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this._get_loggin_data();
    console.log(this.state.username);
}

_get_loggin_data = async () => {
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('username');
  this.setState({username:result})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because JS is single threaded. As soon as `didMount` gets executed, your `_get_login_data` function gets queued up in event loop being async in nature and `didmount` goes on to execute the console statement after which the `_get_login_data` gets actually executed.

You should give a try to write your `didMount` as asynchronous too in order to access await for `_get_login_data` to get executed before the console.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    await this._get_loggin_data();
    console.log(this.state.username);
}
```

I would recommend you to study [Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) in JS and how async and callbacks are treated and executed.